# Creating local profiles in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803

Are 'mandatory local profiles' on Windows 10 running the April 2018 Update (v1803) still possible? If so, how would I go about doing this?

The plan is that students who borrow our 'extra' laptops are able to log in, save files etc. But when the computer shuts down it should pretty much reset to the default set up by us.

This way we can ensure that our devices are always the way we want them to be while removing the action of redeploying our image

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking; you're trying to create a local user? If so, [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026923/windows-10-create-a-local-user-or-administrator-account) have that covered.

Comment: I'm trying to create a local user which students sign into, this user will have a pre set configuration that will reset each time the device reboots. Just so we don't get any student documents flying around on the desktop/in the documents folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  Be sure you explain, in the form of an edit to your question this notion of "mandatory local profiles" because it is a non-standard terminology.  Please make sure you provide any additional information in the form of an edit instead of a comment

Comment: Does the IT Department provide network storage space for user documents, and are the User Profile paths appropriate changed to the network paths? Are the whole PCs reset on reboot like with Faronics DeepFreeze?  Were you able to set "mandantory local profiles" with earlier Windows 10 versions?

Comment: We currently can't provide network storage space for user documents etc. The idea is indeed to reset them just like with Faronics DeepFreeze

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. I heard that these can be easily circumvented. A restore tool like Deep Freeze might work, but I'm guessing you'd buy it if you wanted/had the budget. You might want to look into Reboot Restore Rx. It's a Deep Freeze alternative and is completely free.